# Why is my ASP.NET MVC Edit Form not retaining data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On my edit view, the information doesn't seem to be displayed on the form in the textboxes. Any idea why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's how my edit functions inside the controller look like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var logic = new ContactBUS();
        var user = logic.GetContact(id);
        var mUser = Membership.GetUser(user.Username);
        bool memUserExists = doesUserExist(mUser);

        if (memUserExists)
        {
            var model = new RoleListViewModel
            {
                AllRoles = Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList()
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        return View(logic.GetContact(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
    {
        var logic = new ContactBUS();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            logic.EditContact(contact);
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        else
            return View(contact);
        }
    }
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
    @model ContactWeb.Models.RoleListViewModel
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <div style="float:left;width:350px;">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Form", new ContactWebLibrary.Contact());}
    </div>
```

and Form.cshtml:

```
    @model ContactWebLibrary.Contact
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />
        <fieldset id="ContactEditor">
            <legend>Fields</legend>
            <div>
              @Html.LabelFor(c=>c.FirstName, "First Name")
              @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.FirstName)
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c=>c.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div>
              @Html.LabelFor(c=>c.LastName, "Last Name")
              @Html.TextBoxFor(c=>c.LastName)
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c=>c.LastName)
            </div>
            ...      
            <input type="submit" value="@(Model.Id == 0 ? "Create" : "Edit" )" />
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Comment: How does model get populated in your first action?  does GetallRoles() always return data?

Comment: Why aren't you using an edit template?

Comment: Why are you instantiating something here: `@{Html.RenderPartial("Form", new ContactWebLibrary.Contact());}`? Shouldn't you put your model there instead? Like `@{Html.RenderPartial("Form", Model);}`

Comment: One more thing: what this - `logic.GetContact(id)` - actually returns? Is it something typed after `RoleListViewModel`? If not then you're trying to supply the wrong type to the View which is strongly typed after `RoleListViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memUserExists is true then a new RolesListViewModel is passed to the Edit view.  This in turn passes a brand new Contact model to the partial view each time this partial view is rendered:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Form", new ContactWebLibrary.Contact());}
```

So the contact used in the partial will not contain any information to display, hence, no values are being displayed.

Does logic.GetContact(id) return a RoleListViewModel?  Otherwise, when memUserExists is false, I don't think the following line would work when returning the Edit view:

```
return View(logic.GetContact(id));
```

And also, the following line in your [HttpPost]:

```
return View(contact);
```

This passes a Contact object to a view that is expecting a RoleListViewModel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the logic.GetContact(id) should return a ContactListViewModel. I know it's confusing because there are two view models for the same view.

Comment: You should only pass one view model to the view.  In this case the RolesListViewModel.  If you need to pass the Contact model to the form then you could define this within the RolesListViewModel.  The RolesListViewModel would therefore be the view model and the Contact model would be the form model.

Comment: public class RolesListViewModel { public Contact MyContact { get; set; } }

Comment: But on looking at the view again, the RolesListViewModel is not being used in the view so why not just pass the Contact model in?

Comment: I am using the RoleListViewModel, i didn't include that code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5781/discussion-between-multiv123-and-dangerous)

Comment: please can you help me in chat